# django-allauth caching login and signup pages

Tags: django, django-allauth, django-cache

is there a way to set up Django Redis caching for login and signup views from django-allauth? I looked at docu and found nothing. I don't want whole site caching but only some views and these two are part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django Redis makes use of Django's caching framework. So the documentation bit you are looking for [is here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache).

The short bit:

> A more granular way to use the caching framework is by caching the output of individual views. django.views.decorators.cache defines a cache_page decorator that will automatically cache the view’s response for you.

For allauth, you'd need to match the login and signup URL before you include `allauth.urls` and then [use the decorator in the url conf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#specifying-per-view-cache-in-the-urlconf):

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from allauth.account.views import login

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/login$', cache_page(60 * 15)(login)),
    # same for signup
    url(r'^accounts/$', include('allauth.urls')
]
```

Comment: silly me i thought about using urls but couldn't figure out where to put it, thanks.